# Car topology problem: front quarter panel

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, topology

Well, I'm making this car that will be exported to a game, but I'm having problems with topology.

Everything looks great, but these front quarter panels have very different tones of shades between the faces.

When I render, everything looks good, except in the game, the car look very bad
[image]

[image]

Comment: have you smoothed the object? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like just the camera angle. Move your camera and check if the problem still exists. If it does check your face normals.

Comment: checked the camera and the face normals, both don't have problems